# Correct way to think about thermal noise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I have just started learning about thermal noise in op-amps and while studying could not find if the noise given in op-amps data sheets is random sample to sample regardless of the time interval between the samples or if the randomness of noise is thought about in terms of unit time.

If a data sheet gives the thermal noise (of +3/-3 standard deviations) as 1 uVpp does it mean that out of every thousand samples, 3 will have noise more than ±1 uV at any sample rate? 1000 sps will lead to 3 samples having more than ±1uV noise in a second, 2000 sps will lead to 6 samples having more than ±1uV noise in a second, and so on.

Comment: What have samples got to do with this question. It's an analogue thing not digital.

Comment: Maybe OP means measurement?

Comment: Please link to such a datasheet! I ask because it's not *that* usual to devine peak-to-peak voltages for random things like thermal nose, especially when these things have probability distributions with tails

Comment: Noise is a very tricky concept to think about properly. Best to start with noise power, which is well defined, rather than peak measurements, which are definition sensitive. You also need to consider measurement bandwidth. Data sheets do sometimes specify a peak, but they will have bandwidth assumptions baked into the measurement conditions. At low frequencies, where noise shades into drift, life gets even harder, so 1 s and 10 s noise graphs in data sheets are best treated as pictures, rather than numbers to be compared with other numbers.

Comment: It is a theoretical question, for understanding the concept of thermal noise.

Comment: @Joel in that case, thinking in terms of peak voltages is very misleading, probably. You'll need a good understanding of cumulative probability density functions for the